# New with Ubuntu... having problems

Tags: 18.04

I am unable to login after updating to the latest version of Ubuntu today.
After booting I am stuck on the login screen, unable to move the mouse or press enter.
Is there a quick fix? 
Should I do a factory reset??

Thanks

Comment: What is "the latest version of Ubuntu"? What did you update?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure- I do know it updated the bios

Comment: Sorry I'm REALLY new at this

Comment: It's not clear if you are New (title) or recently Upgraded (body). Have you tried a different mouse? A different keyboard? Do ANY USB peripherals work? Did the install (or upgrade?) display any errors?

Comment: If you are "not exactly sure" what you installed, then plug your USB back in and read it.

Comment: We can't help if you don't tell which Ubuntu release is installed and what you did.

Comment: The Ubuntu installer does NOT upgrade BIOS. So that statement seems rather confusing. Please edit your question to clearly explain what you did, in order, with details.

Comment: Okay. There were system updates available. I beleive they were already downloaded. It prompted me to plug in the power adapter. It finished the update immediately. I reset the computer, it took 10 mins or so to install the updates. Now I cant do anything.

Comment: Again sorry for my illiteracy I have used windows all my life until just now

Comment: So what is the Ubuntu version? What you mean by "I finished the update immediately"?

Comment: Why did you "reset the computer?" What method did you use to "reset"? If you are saying that updates installed AFTER you restarted the computer...then you do not seem to be using Ubuntu. That's a classic Windows feature.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add details there.

Comment: I'm fairly certain its 18.04...